# Urine of my 15 year old diabetic cat suddenly stinks

Tags: cats

This is not normal for my cat and I'm very worried about him. His pee usually doesn't smell so strong. Is this normal for a senior kitty that is diabetic? I just want know what I need to do.

Comment: You need to take the cat to a vet.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get your cat to a vet if you see physical changes. Smelly urine is a clear sign something is wrong, and this will always need veterinary help.

Other types of changes will also need the help of a vet, like if your cat changes eating/drinking habits (starts to drink or eat significantly more/less).

If your cat starts to hide more and withdraw from you if it has been social before, you will need to take it to the vet, as this is a sign something is wrong.

Cats are very good at hiding pain and problems, so even if you are an experienced cat owner, you might have problems recognizing the signs your cat has problems.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said this is something to see the vet about - there's various reasons that could cause a diabetic cat's urine to smell:

- "Musky" or "rotten" smell - This would signal an infection. "Musky" could also be stress hormones.
- "Rotten fruit" or "alcohol" smell - This would be a sign that the sugar in the urine has begun to ferment (normally you'd get this if the urine was left in the litterbox for a couple of hours)
- Stronger than normal urine smell - This would be an indicator that the cat is dehydrated. Are they drinking enough?
- Nail polish remover smell (acetone) - This would be the biggest concern as it would indicate the presence of ketones in the urine, itself a symptom of Diabetic ketoacidosis which is **serious**, as in "get the cat to the vet right now if you want them to live"-type serious.